# Using reserved memory in Linux device drivers

Tags: linux, memory, driver

When writing a device driver that lets the device and the user-space code share some memory, are there any benefits in using [reserved memory](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/reserved-memory/reserved-memory.txt) for this task?

Some things I can think of:

- If the reserved memory is assigned to this particular device alone, other processes won't be able to use up available memory and leave nothing for the driver. This might be especially useful when a large continuous chunk of memory is required by the driver.
- The driver could always use the same fixed (physical) memory address, which might be something the device requires.

Are there any other good reasons (not) to use reserved memory for the driver in this situation?